# Recreating websites with php

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, proxy

At school, there are blocks on sites. I intend to undo that. Even if I don't, I like this idea. So: I have a php page (source.php) to get source code of any site (no cross site ajax).

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET["url"]));
?>
<script>
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0])
   document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href="<?php echo $_GET["url"] ?>";
    else
    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("base").href="<?php
    echo $_GET["url"] ?>");
</script>
```

Simple. Here is the index.html

```
<html><head><title>Unblocker</title></head><body>
<div width="100%" height="10%">
<form onsubmit="return go()">
<input id="url" value="http://www.google.com/">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</div>
<div width="100%" height="90%">
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="100%" height="100%" id="frame">
</iframe>
</div></body></html>
```

And now the javascript (to be inserted into the head tag)

```
function go(){
    url=document.getElementById("url").value;
    frame=document.getElementById("frame");
    //do some url validations, not posting cause doesn't matter
    if(url.isValid)//example
        frame.contentWindow.location=location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname+"/
        source.php?url="+url;
    return false;//to prevent page reload
}
```

A couple of things: First, is this legal, taking whole source codes and displaying them despite my good intent? Also, will it work, or is there anything obvious that can make it better? I know that the server side can't be filtered (assuming that this site is not blocked!). I know that it is very limited, but I might be able to expand it to allow clicking links and all.

Comment: Why not just use a proxy service to go view sites?

Comment: Is this something you need to achieve using coding? Could you not just use a public proxy server and just configure your browser to use that? http://www.publicproxyservers.com/

Comment: You are really bothered about legalities, being that you state that your entire purpose is to circumvent somebody's rules?

Comment: Downloading a page source is *really* illegal, not even my browser does it... wait...

Comment: If TOR is legal, see if the TOR browser bundle can work inside your network. Put this on a flash drive. https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en

Comment: proxies are blocked. we can't download anything like tor (like we can't circumvent the blocks) and I want something lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intend to write a proxy.  I think you should simply use http://www.phpproxy.net or look for a proxy software and install it on your server.

OR you could go on and do it.  You could end up with a product and you will have learned a lot about the HTTP protocol and creating a proxy.  Surely more than you can learn at school.

Proxies are not illegal, but it's probably against your school rules, assuming they have those rules written down somewhere and they didn't forget about the proxy thing.  :)

Comment: phproxy would be blocked since it has the word "proxy" so many times in it, or I would have to remove it all. also, making stuff is fun.

Answer (score 0):

Is it legal?  Sure, you are viewing interpreted source code on every page you go to.  That doesn't mean your school won't flog you for circumventing their firewall.

Will it work?  Yes and no.  You will get the source code, but most likely if you are viewing a blocked domain you won't be able to view any pictures.  Your file_get_contents is grabbing the HTML and the links for the pictures.  To get the pics and replace links your PHP script will have to be somewhat sophisticated.

Comment: yes, of course I'm adding more code. Can I put a <script> tag after the </html> tag? I think google.com did it. You see my altering of base tag so pictues and all show, but links will be blocked if click, working on that

Answer (score 0):

Nice Idea. It sounds like you just want a proxy server tho.

Do you really think the FBI is going to come knocking on your door if they knew your PHP server was getting HTML? absolutely not. Servers everywhere do this every day, such as googlebot. I'd say you're in the clear.

Comment: I seem to think that this is not the standard proxy. Is it? Also, if I password protected this, would a free webhost let me host it?